# wall/write command alternative for Docker Linux?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a use case where I run multiple containers and I want to send messages to specific containers' shells to notify the user working on that shell, over SSH or VS Code or VS Code web.

`wall`/`write` commands are popular in Linux but it doesn't seem to work within Docker.

I understand `wall` or `write` is used to send messages to those who are logged into the system. `who` command usually lists all the users currently logged in. In the docker container with code-server running, I am accessing the shell. But `who` is not able to display that I am logged in. This is why it may not work.

Are there any alternatives? Or is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Disable remote docker access and force users to login with ssh to acces docker. That way they will have to have a login shell. How users get the shell inside containers? What is "specific" about the shells that they have?

Comment: There are 2 ways a user logs in, one via SSH, another via VS Code on Browser i.e code-server. VS Code Desktop uses SSH too!

Comment: FYI, even when users are logged in via SSH, it is not showing.